# Display multiple Enum value in one dropdown list in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I used two Enum in my project. Now I am trying to display these two Enum value in one DropDownList. I am troubled to display two Enum in one DropDownList. I am giving the code below: **1st Enum**

```
public enum Month
    {
        Jan = 1,
        Feb = 2,
        Mar = 3,
        Apr = 4,
        May = 5,
        Jun = 6,
        Jul = 7
    }
```

**2nd Enum**

```
public enum Day
        {
            Sun = 1,
            Mon = 2,
            Tue = 3,
            Wed = 4,
            Thu = 5,
            Fri = 6,
            Sat = 7
        }
```

**I am writing in the controller for combining two Enum using "+" sign:**

```
  foreach (var item in monthdayarray){
lst.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = (Enum.GetName(typeof(Month), item)),   + (Enum.GetName(typeof(Day), item)) , Value = item.ToString() });
}
```

**I am trying to do:** [image]

Comment: What is this supposed to look like for Thu onwards? Post more code too, like the full loop

Comment: Edited in months means 1st ENUM of the code

Comment: Is item an int in a loop?

Comment: Yup its in foreeach loop

Comment: is it ok to use for loop instead of foreach, I have solution with for loop instead of foreach loop

Comment: okay give me solution

Comment: @Pritesh you are doing `Text = (Enum.GetName(typeof(Month), item)),   + (Enum.GetName(typeof(Day), item))` within the loop. I can see a comma just before the '+' sign. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Pritesh, did you get chance to look into my answer

Comment: Yup and Its working nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using foreach you can try with for loop with string interpolation,

something like,

```
for(int i =1; i<= 7; i++)
    Console.WriteLine($"{((Month)i).ToString()} ({((Day)i).ToString()})");
```

If you want to add it in list then

```
for(int i =1; i<= 7; i++)
    lst.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = $"{((Month)i).ToString()} ({((Day)i).ToString()})" , Value = (Month)i });
```

Output will be:

```
Jan (Sun)
Feb (Mon)
Mar (Tue)
Apr (Wed)
May (Thu)
Jun (Fri)
Jul (Sat)
```

POC: [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RXNoYI)